# MySQL Query to pull together two sets of results

Tags: mysql

I run a database that keeps information on rugby referees.  I want to show all the teams that a referee has refereed, and the stats from the games.  I have the MySQL query returning information, but only when a team is the home team, where as I want it to sum all the results and give them to me as a combined figure.

This is my Query:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    T1.Name AS Team, 
    COUNT(M.REF) AS RefCount, 
    SUM(M.HTries) AS Tries, 
    SUM(M.HPT) AS PT, 
    SUM(M.HConv) AS Conv, 
    SUM(M.HPG) AS PG, 
    SUM(M.HDG) AS DG, 
    SUM(M.HYC) AS YC, 
    SUM(M.HRC) AS RC 
  FROM matches M
  LEFT JOIN teams T1 ON T1.TeamID=M.HTeam
  WHERE M.Ref = 2 AND M.date < CURDATE()
  GROUP BY T1.TeamID
UNION 
  SELECT 
    T2.Name as Team,
    COUNT(M.REF) AS RefCount, 
    SUM(M.ATries) AS Tries, 
    SUM(M.APT) AS PT, 
    SUM(M.AConv) AS Conv, 
    SUM(M.APG) AS PG, 
    SUM(M.ADG) AS DG, 
    SUM(M.AYC) AS YC, 
    SUM(M.ARC) AS RC
  FROM matches M
  LEFT JOIN teams T2 ON T2.TeamID=M.ATeam 
  WHERE M.Ref = 2 AND M.date < CURDATE()
  GROUP BY T2.TeamID) AS Teams
GROUP BY Team 
ORDER BY RefCount DESC, Team ASC
```

What it provides is this:

```
+--------------+----------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Team         | RefCount | Tries | PT   | Conv | PG   | DG   | YC   | RC   |
+--------------+----------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| France       |        4 |     3 |    0 |    3 |    6 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
| Argentina    |        2 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
| Australia    |        2 |     5 |    0 |    4 |    1 |    0 |    2 |    0 |
| Ireland      |        2 |     2 |    0 |    2 |    4 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Wales        |        2 |     4 |    0 |    3 |    5 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Barbarians   |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Chiefs       |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Chile        |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Hungary      |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Italy        |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| New Zealand  |        1 |     5 |    0 |    4 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Scotland     |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| South Africa |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    4 |    2 |    0 |    0 |
| Ukraine      |        1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+--------------+----------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

However a basic query for France shows that the RefCount Should be 6 (4 home & 2 away) and this applies to all the results in that they only display home sums.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this query show the correct result?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: The sums, counts and GROUP BY should be a the top level, not within each branch of the UNION.

Comment: Hi @danblack, Thanks for the reply.  I tried this but when I do this it throws up Unknown Column errors for the fields because the from clauses for the tables are within the sub queries.  If I am understanding that wrong, could you throw up an example of what you mean?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Making the aggregates on the outer level:

```
SELECT Team,
       COUNT(RefCount) AS RefCount,
       SUM(Tries) AS Tries,
       SUM(PT) AS PT,
       SUM(Conv) AS Conv,
       SUM(PG) AS PG,
       SUM(DG) AS DG,
       SUM(YC) AS YC,
       SUM(RC) AS RC
FROM
  (SELECT T1.TeamID AS ID,
          T1.Name AS Team,
          M.REF AS RefCount,
          M.HTries AS Tries,
          M.HPT AS PT,
          M.HConv AS Conv,
          M.HPG AS PG,
          M.HDG AS DG,
          M.HYC AS YC,
          M.HRC AS RC
   FROM matches M
   LEFT JOIN teams T1 ON T1.TeamID=M.HTeam
   WHERE M.Ref = 2
     AND M.date < CURDATE()
   UNION SELECT T1.TeamID AS ID,
                T2.Name AS Team,
                M.REF AS RefCount,
                M.ATries AS Tries,
                M.APT AS PT,
                M.AConv AS Conv,
                M.APG AS PG,
                M.ADG AS DG,
                M.AYC AS YC,
                M.ARC AS RC
   FROM matches M
   LEFT JOIN teams T2 ON T2.TeamID=M.ATeam
   WHERE M.Ref = 2
     AND M.date < CURDATE() )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY RefCount DESC,
         Team ASC
```

Note: maybe outer aliases need to be different.

Given the home/away results are the same maybe the `Match` structure should avoid the distinction and have a `ENUM('Home', 'Away')` and a `Opponent UNSIGNED INT` (match ID of opposing game). This would of course require a greater consideration of other queries however if you are early in the process maybe worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for the update @danblack.  I looked at this and gave it a go, I'm getting an error of #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

I've not seen this before so off to look it up, it seems straight forward, but the aliases appear to be there.

Once again, I appreciate your time here.

Comment: I did a quick perusal and it appears that `AND M.date < CURDATE() )` needs to be something like `AND M.date < CURDATE() ) some_alias_name`.